# RcppEigen #define works when using sourceCpp() but ignored with R CMD build

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp, rcppeigen

I've noticed that `sourceCpp()` respects C++ `#define` while `devtools::document()` and `R CMD build` seems to disregard them, at least in the case of Eigen matrix initialization.

Consider this .cpp file:

```
#define EIGEN_INITIALIZE_MATRICES_BY_ZERO

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd initialize_matrix(int nrow, int ncol) {
  return Eigen::MatrixXd(nrow, ncol);
}
```

One may source this file using `sourceCpp`, and then run the following in R:

```
> initialize_matrix(5, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
```

Great, the matrix is initialized with zeros!

Now put the same .cpp file in an RcppEigen package and compile using `devtools::document()` or `R CMD build`.

```
> initialize_matrix(5, 3)
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,] 1.845608e-317 9.881313e-324 9.881313e-324
[2,] 1.107517e-311  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[3,] 9.881313e-324  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[4,]  0.000000e+00 2.121963e-314 9.881313e-324
[5,]  0.000000e+00 1.107517e-311  0.000000e+00
```

The matrix is not initialized with zeros, rather what looks like a memset.

Why does `sourceCpp()` respect the pragma declaration while `devtools::document()` ignores it during compilation?

Comment: A `#pragma` is something different from `#define`, so you should probably be more careful about your language.  As for 'why doesn't devtools...':  you probably want to talk to somebody else. The Rcpp documentation never suggests or recommends devtools; I do not use and cannot help you.  That said, all these tools tend to have _verbose_ modes showing you _exactly_ how the compilers are called.  You may need to do some digging.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for pointing that out.  Compiler calls are the same, I checked the verbose feed. Indeed, the result is the same with `R CMD build` and `devtools::document()` (Q updated). Here's hoping someone from Rstudio/devtools has run across this before. In the meantime I can be more explicit with my Eigen matrix initializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, to be used in a package, you need to add `-DEIGEN_INITIALIZE_MATRICES_BY_ZERO` to `src/Makevars`,
e.g. as in https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/blob/master/src/Makevars#L2 (there are 2 flags for armadillo there).

Or maybe just a problem of ordering? Try putting the `#define` after `#include <RcppEigen.h>`.

Comment: Thanks!! Adding `-DEIGEN_INITIALIZE_MATRICES_BY_ZERO` to `src/Makevars` worked!  I don't think I would have figured that one out.  So appreciated.  No, it's not a problem of ordering -- preprocessor directives can be defined (and should be by best practice) before loading the library headers.